# Hierarchical string structure x.y.z query

Tags: sql, oracle

So I got a string x.y.z that I want to compare with a field in the database.
But if I can't find the string in the database field I want to test find x.y instead and last x if x.y can't be found.

Is it possible to do this in a query if the string can be x-leaf long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIKE` (i.e. `WHERE 'x.y.z' LIKE 'x.y%'` ) or `INSTR()` (i.e. `WHERE INSTR('x.y.z', 'x.y') = 1`) to find the matching rows and then take the longest match:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT   t.*
  FROM     table_name t
  WHERE    'x.y.z' LIKE t.VALUE || '%'
  ORDER BY LENGTH( t.VALUE ) DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I added DESC to the ORDER BY LENGTH to go with the first longest match.

Comment: Good catch - missed that in the query and have added it in now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      where t.col like 'x.%'
      order by (case when t.col = 'x.y.z' then 1
                     when t.col like 'x.y.%' then 2
                     else 3
                end)
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: yes, but what if the string sent to the query is x.y.z.a... ? Then I need to change the query accordingly.